# Why does changing int to long speed up the execution?

Tags: c#

I was trying to solve [problem #14 from Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=14), and had written the following C#...

```
int maxColl = 0;
int maxLen = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++) {
  int coll = i;
  int len = 1;
  while (coll != 1) {
    if (coll % 2 == 0) {
      coll = coll / 2;
    } else {
      coll = 3 * coll + 1;
    }
    len++;
  }
  if (len > maxLen) {
    maxLen = len;
    maxColl = i;
  }
}
```

Trouble was, it just ran and ran without seeming to stop.

After searching for other people's solution to the problem, I saw one looking very similar, except that he had used long instead of int. I didn't see why this should be necessary, as all of the numbers involved in this problem are well within the range of an int, but I tried it anyway.

Changing int to long made the code run in just over 2 seconds.

Anyone able to explain this to me?

Comment: Just changing from int to long shouldn't make that dramatic of a difference.  I suspect you have an overflow that is preventing the while loop from breaking.  watch it in the debugger and see if you can't figure out if there's an overflow somewhere.

Comment: Normally Int64 is slower than Int32. You have maybe an overflow handling here which causes that Int32 is slower.

Comment: @Ben it's normally equally fast except for division and a few complex operations. On some systems operating on 32-bit values are even slower because you need sign/zero extension and masking to convert to 64-bit values

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When `i` equals 113383, the 3X+1 sequence at some point exceeds the maximum value of an `int`, so `3 * coll + 1` overflows and becomes negative:

> 113383 → 340150 → ... → 1654740898 → 827370449 → −1812855948 → −906427974 → ...

Eventually, the sequence winds up in the following cycle of negative numbers:

> ... → −17 → −50 → −25 → −74 → −37 → −110 → −55 → −164 → −82 → −41 → −122 → −61 → −182 → −91 → −272 → −136 → −68 → −34 → −17

This cycle doesn't include 1, so your loop never terminates.

Using `long` instead of `int` ensures that `coll` never overflows.

Comment: Aargh! I thought I had checked for that. Explains why I had similar problems with some other questions as well.

Answer (score 24):

Your integers are overflowing and becoming negative.
Therefore, your loop never actually terminates.
If you wrap your code in a `checked` block, you'll see an overflow exception instead.

`long` is large enough to store the values you need, so that works fine.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Yours and Michael Liu's came in at the same time, and his had slightly more explanation, so I'm making his as the answer, but yours was very helpful as well. Thanks very much.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel To be fair, SLaks was two minutes faster :)